# Does the certificate need to be official or self signed?

Tags: ssl, https, poodle-attack

I am putting a web test up for clients that visit "https://oursite.com/poodlesecurityfailed.js"

Question,

Do I need a valid certificate even though its on a test domain for certificate negotiation? If client can visit it, they failed the poodle test. (SSLv3 is enabled) on that host.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need a valid certificate even though its on a test domain for certificate negotiation? If client can visit it, they failed the poodle test. (SSLv3 is enabled) on that host.

Depends on the client.

If the clients is has enough knowledge to understand, that "invalid certificate" when accessing the site means in reality that the client has still SSL 3.0 enabled, then a self-signed certificate would be enough.

If you instead want to provide an explanation of the problem at this site and don't expect the client to explicitly accept an invalid certificate just to see this explanation, then you should better use a properly trusted certificate.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it easier. I think a 'trusted' cert should be okay on it, since the SSLv3 wont do much on a domain with one file?

Comment: I think if you just send information which you would send over a less secure transport too, than it does not matter much. But there are still enough users which don't know that SSL/TLS is just for transport security and believe that  by accessing a site by https they are immune against all dangers. Thus users could be tricked by the apparently "trusted" certificate even though the connection is unsafe. But these kind of users can probably tricked in much simpler ways so I would not care.